# Is there somewhere I can search for available webservices?

Tags: web-services, api, mashup

I'm wondering if there is a website that collects (and hopefully updates) information on available web services.

Edit: Thanks for all the info; many good answers. I can only accept 1 as the "accepted answer" at this time, so I picked my favorite one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about http://www.programmableweb.com/apis? It has a fairly large list of popular Web Services and a quick info sheet on each, including how to access it.

Answer (score 13):

[webservicelist](http://www.webservicelist.com) is one place..

Answer (score 3):

Back when webservices were going to take over the world, I stumbled upon [xmethods.net](http://www.xmethods.net/). It's still around, but I can no longer vouch for it's accuracy or timeliness. Note the dated blurb:

> Emerging web services standards such as SOAP, WSDL and UDDI will enable system-to-system integration that is easier than ever before.

Googling [web services list](http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=web+services+list) points to a couple higher rated sites that you'd probably want to  check out as well:

- the aptly named http://www.webservicelist.com/
- http://www.webservicex.net

Personally, I've discovered that random, free web services are more trouble than they're worth. Pretty much anything they're doing*, I can more effectively and more reliably provide myself for minimal cost.

If I'm looking for a solution to a specific problem, eg. storing credit card data securely, then I'll evaluate the options in that space - web service or not.

- Notable exceptions include accessing proprietary data, such as CDDB or Amazon. But, if I need that data, a quick google will turn up who has high quality data - then it's on to find an API for it.

Answer (score 3):

NOAA provides a great (and free) collection of weather webservices that you can use,

http://www.weather.gov/xml/

Answer (score 2):

Not really a web site, but you can use [UDDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDDI) to find information on what web services are offered by businesses that publish service listings.  There are several client implementations listed at the bottom of the page I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

**Seekda.com** for "Big" (WS-*) services only, based on WSDL/SOAP. Let me know if you've found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://usgovxml.com . USGovXML.com is an index to publicly available web services and XML data sources provided by the U. S. government.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]. Please don't answer such questions; instead, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.